# Why values from two way DataBinding in android can be read only by providing model in method which should have new values?

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding

I have ViewModel:

```
public class CalculatorViewModel implements CalculatorMVVM.ViewModel {

    private static final String TAG = CalculatorViewModel.class.getSimpleName();

    private CalculatorMVVM.Model model;

    public CalculatorViewModel(CalculatorMVVM.Model model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public ObservableField<Double> price = new ObservableField<>(1.0);
    public ObservableField<Double> quantity = new ObservableField<>(1.0);

    @Override
    public void onButtonClick(CalculatorMVVM.ViewModel viewModel) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onButtonClick: price = " + viewModel.price.get() + ", quantity = " + viewModel.quantity.get());
    }
}
```

ViewModel has method onButtonClick which should be able to read new, changed values.

And in layout I have `data` part:

```
<data>
    <variable name="viewModel" type="CalculatorMVVM.ViewModel"/>
</data>
```

and, among others, fields like:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrice"
    ...
    android:text="@={viewModel.price}"
    />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editQuantity"
    ....
    android:text="@={viewModel.quantity}"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClick(viewModel)}"
    />
```

So, my question is:

**Why do I have to provide viewModel to my `onButtonClick` method, when I am already calling method of that particular object?** When I tried to do that (calling method without `viewModel` parameter), I received only default values of those fields, even though they were changed before clicking on that button.

Comment: Have you set the model by calling `binding.setViewModel(viewModel)`?

Comment: Is `CalculatorMVVM.ViewModel` part of your code? Did you declare `onButtonClick()`? The `viewModel` parameter seems redundant.

Comment: @SifatOshan, yes I did.

Comment: @tynn, answer to your both questions is yes. And yes, it seems redundant, that's why I asked this question in the first place. When I try to make this call without parameter, I don't have changed values, but default ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get rid of the redundancy you can simply do this:

```
<data>
    <import type="com.example.Conversion"/>
    <variable
       name="viewModel"
       type="com.example.ViewModel" />
</data>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editPrice"
    ...
    android:text="@={Conversion.toString(viewModel.price)}"
    />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editQuantity"
    ....
    android:text="@={Conversion.toString(viewModel.quantity)}"
     />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    ...
    android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onButtonClick()}"
    />
```

**Conversion.Java**

```
public class Conversion {

    @InverseMethod("toDouble")
    public static String toString(Double doubleNum) {
        return doubleNum == 0.0 ? null : String.valueOf(doubleNum);
    }

    public static Double toDouble(String string) {
        return string.isEmpty() ? 0.0 : Double.parseDouble(string);
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.Java**

```
public ObservableField<Double> price = new ObservableField<>(1.0);
public ObservableField<Double> quantity = new ObservableField<>(1.0);

    @Bindable
    public Double getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    @Bindable
    public Double getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price) {
        if(getPrice() == price) return;
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public void setQuantity(Double quantity) {
        if (getQuantity()==quantity) return;
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public void onButtonClick() {
        Log.d("onButtonClick", "price = " + price.get() + ", quantity = " + quantity.get());
    }
```

And also you need to handle `java.lang.NumberFormatException`

Comment: This solution is correct. Very elegant. **I just don't need in my code getters and setter, which is great!** Of course, `java.lang.NumberFormatException` should be handled, but anyone who would try this code without it, would soon face this exception. :)

Comment: @DevetiPutnik I would stay away from doing any complex `logical reasoning` inside the layout file itself. In my opinion, it should be done separately even before your viewModel class is being used by your view.

Comment: @beerBear, I don't understand what you mean by that for the code provided above.